# Something wrong with a circuit designed

Tags: power-supply, comparator

This is a circuit that we designed at AllAboutCircuits to control a solenoid valve.

The circuit tries to leave the solenoid valve deactivated if the PT100 is submerged in nitrogen and to activate when it has been out of nitrogen for a while.

[image: the circuit]

The [link to the forum](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/solved-control-solenoid-valve-with-arduino-or-with-circuit.187551/page-3?cb=1676878978). The thing is that I use an Arduino relay which includes the transistor/diode and resistor so it works correctly. I connected the negative to the output of the comparator and the positive/signal to the positive of the power supply. I was using a portable source to feed the circuit and at the same time the solenoid valve but now for whatever reason it doesn't work. I have redone the circuit many times but there must be something I am not understanding. It doesn't work with the external source even if it offers 24V and if I use a normal laboratory source now I need to give it 35 volts for the relay to activate. Ask me whatever you want, I'm not very good at asking these types of questions even if I try hard but I'll paste photos and the link to AAC.

The circuit is the simplest in the world, it only uses a resistor bridge at the input with a PT100 for the comparator to activate the relay.
I have change to the LM339 to the LM393. R5 is 20ohm, but this worked.

I only need to know why before worked with 24 for the circuit and electrovalve and now no is insufficient to the circuit only.

The Arduino relay should include R6, Q1, D1, relay.

[image]
[image]

I think that to specify more, it is like, if the relay needs only 3 volts to work (both positive and signal) it does not work with the 24 source and if I increase it to 35 with a laboratory source, it is capable of reaching 3V.

If I use the external source, it stays at 2.6V.
You have to see some theory that I don't understand.

Comment: That little relay module you have there needs 0V, 5VDC and a control signal (5-12VDC). If I'm reading it correctly, you've put 24V (and subsequently 35V) across a 5V coil and want to know why it's not working?

Comment: the yellow and brown wires are both connected to the same place

Comment: as a general tip, when thinking about or describing a problem, it's always good to start by properly describing the problem you are trying to solve (a.k.a. requirements). Clarifies the mind and makes life easier for others. You haven't actually told us *how* the valve should be controlled which is important. Perhaps you might modify your question to fix this.

Comment: @Mukira that's worked.

Comment: @jsotola yeah, they are the positive and signal wire.

Comment: @danmcb sure, let me try better, that was because the problem was done and I wanted to do more easily to answer for you. Let me edit.

Comment: @Mukira I made a voltage divider and it didn't work either, it's not that the relay melted and it doesn't work, it works but it kind of needs more voltage than it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've fixed it, I've unsoldered the module's relay, I've used a diode, a 1k resistor and a 2n2222 npn and it works again. Greetings.

Comment: Do not ask a question in an answer

Comment: @DavideAndrea Sure, thanks!